# How to use value from an object as a key for another object

Tags: typescript

I have an object like this

```
import {
    imageOne,
    imageTwo
} from "./images";

export const imageKeyMap = {
    "one": imageOne,
    "two": imageTwo
}
```

`imageOne` and `imageTwo`  are defined like this

```
import treeImage from "assets/images/tree.jpg";
import sunImage from "assets/images/sun.jpg"

interface Image {
    alt: string,
    src: any,
}

export const imageOne: Image = {
        alt: '...',
        src: treeImage
}

export const imageTwo: Image = {
        alt: '...',
        src: sunImage
}
```

Now I want to use the image as a value for another object. I want to access the value (thus the image `treeImage`, `sunImage`) of `imageKeyMap` with a key (which is a string), coming from another object.

```
interface BarProps {
    key: string,
    headline: string,
    subtitle: string
}

interface FooBarProps {
    image: Image,
    headline: string,
    subtitle: string,
}

someArray.map((element: BarProps) => {
     const {key, headline, subtitle } = element
     return { 
         image: imageKeyMap[key], // <- this is highlighted
         headline: headline,
         subtitle: subtitle
     } as FooBarProps 
})
```

But this gives me

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ one: Image; two: Image; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ one: Image; two: Image;}'.

Why can't I use the `key` as the `key` for the `imageKeyMap`?

Comment: Try `imageKeyMap[key as keyof BarProps]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highlighted bit says (emphasis mine)

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ one: Image; two: Image; }'.
> **No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ one: Image; two: Image; }'**

So you just need to specify that there is a string indexer possible on your `imageKeyMap`.

There are various options (some more typesafe than others) but at very minimum this works:

```
const imageKeyMap : {[key:string]: Image} = {
    "one": imageOne,
    "two": imageTwo
}
```

[Typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

For `imageKeyMap` object, the type of key is `"one"|"two"`, but in `BarProps`, the key is `string`. The type `string` is not a subset of `"one"|"two"`.

So either change the key to `keyof typeof imageKeyMap`, or change the type of imageKeyMap object to `Record<string, Image>`.

[Here is an example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFs4HMUG8BQyRycANmAFzIDOYUoWANIcdVAlXCAJ7MC++fAgD2IWsmCYcAeRAQqGbCgC8yAsQ0lyVAOQA6AzuabW7KgCI6ECIpzn8AoaPGSlAFQDuwhVJVqWJmSUyPqGxiY0Zsjm1ACuILYQ9o4iYmASvgDSENwAsnAADsiq6sTmoklUrjJy4USWXuZVvp7CDoJg3AUo2dzSMPlFqgDWOcIwyJ3d4xlKvYMA3IKp4sJgABbQifOFVABKECJQACYAPLT0IExovgB8xf4a5XJNszUQddFgjc3uXu34KYoaQbaC9fqDB6jbgzIEzNabKDbHKLfBAA)

Comment: How is `OtherKeyOfMap` used?

Comment: It's just a calculation to show the type of `otherImageKeyMap`'s key is `string`. You can use `string` directly.